# Try to install Clockworkmod Recovery, always getting stock recovery

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-epic-4g

I'm trying to install Cyanogenmod on my Samsung Epic 4G.  I've tried a couple of ways to get Clockworkmod Recovery on the phone, but every time I boot it into recovery mode I get the stock recovery program.  I've tried the method listed on the Cyanogenmod wiki [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Epic_4G%3a_Full_Update_Guide) and one using Odin [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/install-clockworkmod-recovery-5-0-epic-4g/), but every time it boots, it loads up with stock.

Does anyone have any ideas for how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the key was holding down volume-down, power, and camera buttons until the capacitive buttons (home, search, etc) lit up, which was longer than until the screen flashed (as stated in the CyanogenMod wiki).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to to [flash clockwork mod](http://forums.acsyndicate.net/showthread.php?3331-ACS-How-to-Root-Clockworkmod-Flash-Roms-Unroot-Tips-%2824-videos%29-12-9-11)  recovery over your default stock recovery.
Then get into Clockworkmod recovery.
After that you can flash any CynogenMod roms.
Use [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1274337) guide to work with Odin.

Comment: That was not the issue.  Using various guides I did install clockwork mod recovery "over" the stock recovery, unfortunately the guide you linked does not provide further information from the ones I already linked.  Additionally, the problem was _how_ to get into Clockworkmod recovery, which you didn't address. Apparently the Epic 4G (not the Touch) keeps a copy of the stock recovery somewhere which it boots if you don't hold down the noted buttons for long enough.